# Wait until state occur in Java for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, while-loop, wait

**UPDATE:**

I made a new and more specific question here: [Implementing wait() and notify() between multiple sensor connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900887/implementing-wait-and-notify-between-multiple-sensor-connections)

**OLD QUESTION:**

I am trying to connect to multiple devices through Bluetooth in my Android app using a single button. It works fairly ok, but sometimes the devices doesn't finish connecting before continuing to the next device in the for loop.

Every sensor connection state can have four states. I would like to have my for loop wait until state 2 has been reached before continuing to the next sensor. Is that possible? I Tried implementing a while loop, but it doesn't work.

```
public void onConnectSensors() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Connect to sensors 0-9

        int state = mScanAdapter.getConnectionState(i);
        BluetoothDevice device = mScanAdapter.getDevice(i);

        switch (state) {

            case CONN_STATE_DISCONNECTED:

                ...

            case CONN_STATE_CONNECTING:

                ...

            case CONN_STATE_CONNECTED:

                ...

            case CONN_STATE_RECONNECTING:

                ...
        }
        while (mScanAdapter.getConnectionState(i) != 2) {
            try {
                wait();          // waits until state 2 has been reached
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method works in conjunction with notify; could you try to use sleep (https://www.journaldev.com/1020/thread-sleep-java) instead?

Comment: How do you use device object here? I guess it should give you an access the state of connection not the adapter.

Comment: int state = mScanAdapter.getConnectionState(i);

gets the connection state of each specific sensor i.

Comment: @FrederikPetri, I see that you already got an answer. From a design perspective it will be good to stick with wait and notify rather than using sleep.

Comment: Your notify can be based on the listener something like BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener onServiceConnecte(), not completely sure about the interface used, but that is the idea

Comment: In the end the answer below didn't work for me. I made a new and more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900887/implementing-wait-and-notify-between-multiple-sensor-connections. My notify is now called when sensor has established connection, however I still got problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```java
public void onConnectSensors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Connect to sensors 0-9

        int state = mScanAdapter.getConnectionState(i);
        BluetoothDevice device = mScanAdapter.getDevice(i);

        while (state != 2) {
            // handle other states here if you want

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); //sleep a second before retry
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle errors
            }

            state = mScanAdapter.getConnectionState(i);
        }

        // handle state 2 here
    }
}
```

If state != 2 than code execution will be paused for a sec, than it retries (asks for the state again). I'm sure it can be done without a blocking sleep too if it's a problem.