# Implementing wait() and notify() between multiple sensor connections

Tags: java, while-loop, wait, notify

In my Android app I would like to connect to multiple sensors with one button OnClickListener. However, It needs to take each sensor at a time until connection has been established before moving on to the next.

`onSensorConnected` is called when a sensor is succesfully connected. However, right now it is trying to connect to the next sensor before `onSensorConnected` is called.

Therefore, I tried to implement a `wait()` when a sensor is connecting (`onConnectSensors`) and a `notify()` when connection has been established (`onSensorConnected`). This should allow the next sensor to go through the same process.

However, sensors are still connecting before the `notify` signal in `onSensorConnected`. I need some guidance in how to use the `wait` and `notify`.

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {

    Button connect;
    
    private Boolean sensorConnected = false;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, container,false);

        connect = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onConnectSensors(0); // Connect sensor one at a time..
                onConnectSensors(1);
                onConnectSensors(2);
                onConnectSensors(3);
                onConnectSensors(4);
                onConnectSensors(5);
                onConnectSensors(6);
                onConnectSensors(7);
                onConnectSensors(8);
                onConnectSensors(9);
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    // Position is the sensor position in a recyclerview
    public void onConnectSensors(int position) {

        BluetoothDevice device = mScanAdapter.getDevice(position);
        mSensorViewModel.connectSensor(getContext(), device);
        // Sensor is now establishing connnection...

        // Wait until recieving sensorConnected = true
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while ( sensorConnected != true ) { // Wait until sensorConnected is true
                    lock.wait();
                }
                sensorConnected = false; // reset status for next sensor
            }
        } catch ( InterruptedException x ) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorConnected() { // This is called automatically when sensor is finishing connection

        synchronized ( lock ) {
            sensorConnected = true;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any concurrency in your code just some `wait()`, `notify()` and `synchronized` but no other threads?... It seems that the most important part is missing here. Please clarify that

Comment: What I meant is that I don't see any other threads, e.g. you're invoking all sensors sequencially in a single thread. And if every of the sensors calls that `onSensorConnected` after it is finished, then it is clear that the other sensors have not been initialized (because you're not invoking them all at once). So you should just remove these `wait()` and `notify()` calls completely and call `onSensorConnected` in your `onClick` method

Comment: Sorry if my question and code is not clear enough. Actually I need to connect to each sensor one at at time and wait for onSensorConnected() between each connection. Right now all sensors are connected too quickly before onSensorConnected() is reached for each sensor. I will try to clarify the question and code, thanks.

Comment: Why? If the API allows connects to be concurrent, why do you want to override that?

Comment: I think it is overloading the bluetooth protocol. Only a few sensors are connected and some just start connecting but never fully connect. However, when I manually "click" one sensor at a time and wait for 'onSensorConnected' it works. Now I just want to automate that process